# Why does ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Range.Clearcontens give Application-defined or Object-defined error?

Tags: excel, vba

I wonder why the following line gave

> "Application-defined or Object-defined error"

If `Sheet6` is selected, this line runs fine - no error message. However, if another sheet is selected, Excel throws the above error message.

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet6").Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(12, 1000).End(xlToLeft)).ClearContents
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to qualify all your **Range** objects with your **Worksheet**.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet6")
    .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(12, 1000).End(xlToLeft)).ClearContents
End With
```

You didn't qualify `Cells()` with your worksheet, so it pulls from the `ActiveSheet` instead of `Worksheets("Sheet6")`.

So, remember that when your thinking *"It only works when it's on that sheet"* then this is going to be the issue.

Comment: Thanks. Now that you pointed it out, I remember I had a similar problem few years back. I had solved the problem by qualifying Cells but the solution escaped me this time.